# VBA Opening multiple PDFs

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I can get one PDF to open by selecting the file name however i don't have the knowledge to loop through multiple file names.

I've gotten this far already:

```vb
Sub OpenPDF()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pth As String

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range of cells:", Type:=8)
    pth = "A:\Pay run\$\"

    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink pth & rng & ".pdf"
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a loop:

```
Sub OpenPDF()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pth As String
    Dim c as Range

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range of cells:", Type:=8)
    pth = "A:\Pay run\$\"

    For Each c in rng.Cells
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink pth & c & ".pdf"
    Next c
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried adding that loop however i now get a syntax error. Could you show how it would be incorporated into the code above. Thank you

Comment: what is exactly the syntax error?

Comment: Compile error: Syntax error in the "For c in rng.Cells" line

Comment: yep, I've missed `Each`